# Change Orders Currency in WooCommerce via a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I don't have anything to start with, only that I'm stuck. I migrated an **Ecwid** Store to **Woocommerce** via an external Service (talked with their support for hours and they deny it's their fault).

Let's cut to the chase, the Store currency of the Original Store and the new is **Euro** (**no** Multi-currency enabled), but all imported Orders are shown in **USD** and it says the order was made in **USD**, is there a way to change all past orders to Euro via `MySql` or via a function, I searched for a long time and all I found was concerning orders to be made or Problems mit Multi-currency. Changing the Order Currency is vital because of the external Software used for Taxes.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This seems to be very complicated if you need to convert all prices from one currency to another (a real nightmare). Now if you need to change just the currency without prices conversion, that is very easy

Comment: I just need to convert them to another currency with no conversion whatsoever.  I achieved it with a CSV Ex- and Import. But It should be possible over mySQL I guess I'm just not that proefficent in mySQL and can't find where the information is stored

Comment: Ok so in this case, I have answered and you will see that is something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WordPress class `WPDB` will allow you to run a simple SQL query to change all related orders currency from "USD" to "EUR".

Always make a database backup before.

Paste this code in `function.php` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*:

```
// Simple SQL query in a function
function change_orders_currency_from_usd_to_eur(){
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
        SET meta_value = 'EUR'
        WHERE meta_key = '_order_currency'
        AND meta_value = 'USD'
    " );
}
// Run the function
change_orders_currency_from_usd_to_eur();
```

You will use and run the code below once, browsing any page of your web site.

---

Or you can run this SQL query directly from phpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 'EUR'
WHERE meta_key = '_order_currency'
AND meta_value = 'USD'
```

Bothe are tested and work.

Comment: The SQL query didn't work on the server my client is using but the function.php addiction is working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If the order values are correct and not converted, it looks like a display issue only. This means updating some setting or update some html file or template.

If the order value is not correct, you need to locate the tables in the database where these values are stored (or originating from). Order totals are sometimes just a sum of orderlines. Once located, you need to run an update query on the affected rows which converts the currency.

Comment: The order value is correct, only the currencies are wrong in the backend, Products are in all in €, but if I add a new Product to the Order it just shows as USD.

I can't seem to find the affected row and thus can't make any update query (I also am not quite sure about the Syntax)